# how can i create a div shape like the one i have shared with 100% width

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image]

I want create a `div` with a shape as shown above and I want it to be 100% width.

Below is the HTML and CSS that I tried.
I was able to make a triangle but it doesn't work with 100% width of `div`:

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle-up"><div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 25%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

Comment: i know its a triangle but how can i make a shape like above green shape?

Comment: You can check JSBIN now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pogog/1/edit?html,css,output)

HTML

```
  <div class="container"><div class="triangle-up"><div></div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.container{ 
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #000; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 24%;
}
.triangle-up div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 900px solid #4679BD;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: cant set width of that green div to 100%?

Comment: @user2837485 are you talking about triangle? I have used border property to set it, can't set border to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

how about 3d css transformation?

html:

```
<div class="triangle-up"><div></div></div>
```

css:

```
body{
   background:black;
}
.triangle-up div{
width:400px;
    height:150px;
    background:cyan;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(40deg);
    margin:50px;
}
.triangle-up{
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
}
```

here is an example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/FYj5y/)

EDIT:

basically you give the container div `triangle-up` a depth of 500px; and you rotate the inner div by its y-axis.

a more thorough explanation can be found in [THIS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/06/adventures-in-the-third-dimension-css-3-d-transforms/) nice article.

Comment: great one dude can you explain it

Comment: how can i have it without 3d ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo elements with `transform:rotate()`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/N3njW/)**

[image: css shaped div with image in background]

This makes 2 seperate elements (the pseudo elements `:before/:after`) with the same background color as the div and rotates them to create your desired shape.

- You can display an image in the background.
- Responsive width and height.
- As the tranform property isn't on the `div` element, it will alow you to put content in your shape without transfoming it.
- Less *HTML* markup.

*HTML :*

```
 <div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    height:40%;
    margin:10% 0 0;
    background:#1EC8D7;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2
}
div:after,div:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background:#1EC8D7;
    width:110%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    right:0;
}
div:before{
    top:0;

    transform-origin:100% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;

    transform:rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
}
div:after{
    bottom:0;

     transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;

    transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
```